# Read only user access denied to weblogic admin console

Tags: weblogic

I am trying to create user with Read only permissions for development team to have access to weblogic console , I know the process is simple but for some reason after creating the user i am not able login using the Read only user.

Below steps to create read only user:

1. Login into Weblogic Admin Console as weblogic user (administrator) ,Then => security realms -> myrealm => users&groups =>New "User" created “appdev” user with password “password01”.
2. Once user is created, selected username => selected Groups Tab => Selected group by name “Monitors”. Saved the changes made.
3. Logged out and closed the browser.
4. Restarted the server and Opened a new browser window.
5. Attempting to login with the new user is returning access denied.

We are using weblogic 9.2 version.

Comment: Did you remember to click "[save](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/ConsoleHelp/taskhelp/security/AddUsersToGroup.html)"? Okay I see that you did now... sorry.

Comment: I would go back into the server and see if you can confirm the password, or reset it even. Use copy & paste just to be sure. Typos happen.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below link and try to enable refresh replica at startup option and bounce the server and check.

Navigate to weblogic admin console ->Domain->Security->Embedded LDAP->Refresh Replica At StartUp

Detailed descriptions are written below:
http://www.techpaste.com/2013/10/weblogic-admin-server-startup-hanging-coming-running-state/#comment-4532